# duckdb syntax error for materialized CTEs

Tags: r, common-table-expression, duckdb

I am trying to create a query with [Materialized CTEs](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/query_syntax/with.html#materialized-ctes) but I get a syntax error (in this case with R, but the problem is independent of R, I hope...).

The query that throws an error looks like this (very close to the example given in the [documentation](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/query_syntax/with.html#materialized-ctes))

```sql
WITH avg_cte AS MATERIALIZED (
  SELECT carrier, MEAN(dep_delay) AS avg_dep_delay
  FROM flights
  GROUP BY carrier
)
SELECT * FROM avg_cte
```

A MWE with R would look like this

```
cc <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
DBI::dbWriteTable(cc, "flights", nycflights13::flights)

q <- "WITH avg_cte AS MATERIALIZED (
  SELECT carrier, MEAN(dep_delay) AS avg_dep_delay
  FROM flights
  GROUP BY carrier
)
SELECT * FROM avg_cte
"
DBI::dbGetQuery(cc, q)
#> Error: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "MATERIALIZED"
#> LINE 1: WITH avg_cte AS MATERIALIZED (
```

Comment: The `MATERIALIZED` keyword is new in 0.9.0, but the current R duckdb package is on 0.8.1-3.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for pointing that out! (If you want the points for this, feel free to post this as an answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MATERIALIZE` keyword is new in 0.9.0, however the current R package is still only 0.8.1-3. The "bleeding edge" [installation instructions](https://duckdb.org/docs/installation/) should allow 0.9.0 to be installed in the meantime.

```r
install.packages('duckdb', repos=c('https://duckdb.r-universe.dev', 'https://cloud.r-project.org'))
```